# How do I change href generation in UI-Router for Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, subdomain, router

I am trying to add subdomain support to UI-Router. Imagine these routes with custom attribute 'domain':

```
{ name: 'mainhome', url: '/', domain: 'example.com', component: 'MainSiteComponent' },
{ name: 'bloghome', url: '/', domain: 'me.example.com',
component: 'BlogComponent' },
```

> NOTE: both routes have the same route url

I am trying to change the generation of href by the uiSref directive, based on the current domain **AND** the custom domain property.

Active route should be determined as either "mainhome" or "bloghome" depending on the current domain.

When visiting **http://example.com/**:

`<a uiSref="mainhome">` becomes `<a href="/">`

`<a uiSref="bloghome">` becomes `<a href="http://me.example.com/">`

When visiting **http://me.example.com/**:

`<a uiSref="mainhome">` becomes `<a href="http://example.com/">`

`<a uiSref="bloghome">` becomes `<a href="/">`

I'd really appreciate any help regarding this!

Comment: I imagine I would use Dependency Injection (DI) to inject my custom services but I am at a loss of how to do that. Do I have to fork ui-router/core and iu-router/ng2 ?!

Answer (score 1):

ui-router is built to manipulate the path part of the URL not the hostname so your best option is probably to build 2 separate apps.

You can control the next state your app will move to using a transition hook which you can use to catch the next transition and if it's from a different domain you can then change the browser location to this domain.

TLDR; there is a [plunker sample](https://embed.plnkr.co/Sf7yPORXZFjPDQ15YKEV/) based on ui-router hello-world

First lets define the states:

```
const states = [
    { name: 'mainhome', url: '/', host: 'example.com', component: 'MainSiteComponent' },
    { name: 'bloghome', url: '/', host: 'me.example.com', component: 'BlogComponent' },
]
```

And let's define an `onStart` transition hook that will be called before any transition is done to a new state and will check if the next state has a different host than the current host.

```
function uiRouterConfigFn(router: UIRouter, injector: Injector) {
    router.transitionService.onStart({to: "*"}, function($transition) {
         const nextState = $transition.to();
         const host = window.location.host;
         if (nextState && nextState.host && nextState.host !== host) {
             window.location = `${window.location.protocol}://${nextState.host}/${nextState.url}`;
        }
    });
}
```

Finally use `config` to call our configuration function:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        ...,
        UIRouterModule.forRoot({ states: states, config: uiRouterConfigFn })
   ],
   ...
})
class RootAppModule {}
```

Comment: I have thought about the first bit of code as well however I need to be able to access both sets at the same time, whilst having the correct hostname depending on which one you are currently on. I imagine there is some way to hook onto the code somehow (uiSref) to allow this, but I am confused as how to proceed. I don't mind if it means creating a new directive say, myUiSref, then perhaps from that wrap some code around it. It would also need to be able to choose a correct state based on a custom property.

Comment: what do you mean by `I need to be able to access both sets at the same time`

Comment: a <a uiSref="routeName" mySet="firstset (or secondset)"> but the link would also include http://appopriateDomainOfSet/theroute

Comment: I think you'll find that you have 2 different sets of links

Comment: can you add other route samples?

Comment: ok, assume href is the link we get from uiSref. when visiting example.com `<a href="/">Home</a>` and `<a href="http://blog.example.com/">Blog Home</a>` BUT when visiting from blog.example.com, the exact same template code results in an effective `<a href="http://example.com/">Home</a>` and `<a href="/">Blog Home</a>`. Note they are either relative or absolute depending on which one it is, and from which site you are viewing it on

Comment: i mean apart form "home" do you have other routes that you want to share or switch?

Comment: well its not just sharing its also creating the appropriate link (with correct domain). The refresh will take place automatically when the use clicks on a link with the other domain. we could have ones from blog1.example.com that will point to blog2.example.com etc. /forums on example.com will be different to blog1.example.com/forums even though its the same URI itll be a different route and each site needs to refer to the appropriate domain of that 'state set'